# debian buster sudo apt-get upgrade does nothing

Tags: debian, installation, package-management, apt

I just installed Debian buster on 30 sep. apt-get works very well and I am able to update my system. But running apt-get upgrade always does nothing.

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Is this a problem?

Here is my sources.list

`deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib`

`###
buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate for your mirror of choice.`


`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free`

Comment: update and upgrade meanings are different?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your package lists using `apt-get update`. Then you should be able to upgrade packages using `apt-get upgrade`.

[This Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/222352) should clear up any confusion between updating and upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

> `apt-get` works very well and I am able to update my system. But running `apt-get upgrade` always does nothing.

Your `sources.list` is configured correctly and your system is up-to-date.

This system update (index update /package upgrade) can be done automatically through the `unattended-upgrades` , it can be configured to handle the security + other available updates.

The `apt-daily.timer` and `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` control the `apt-daily.service` and `apt-daily-upgrade.service` (like a cronjob) which run in background to keep the system updated.

To check it:

```
sudo systemctl list-timers --all
```

Check you mail box and the dpkg log files.

> UnattendedUpgrades could, in theory, be used for this purpose as well. A simple hack would be to use suites like stable instead of codenames like jessie in the sources.list and unattended-upgrades may just do the right thing. Unfortunately, that will do the upgrade at an uncontrolled time, something which we may want to avoid. So unattended-upgrades would need to be able to edit the sources.list.
>
> unattended-upgrades also has no user-visible interface, which could be a major issues for less knowledgable desktop users. Major upgrades are likely to trigger questions and issues, as we saw in the design document and while we aim to reduce those interruptions, completely silencing them eventually, we need a way to interact with the user in the end to let them know if some decisions remain to be done.
>
> unattended-upgrades runs under cron (and not screen) so it could, in theory, be interrupted by an broken upgrade of cron. it may be useful to have it run detached from cron, under screen or at least with heavy logging, for major upgrades.

[Debian: Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

[AutomatedUpgrade : unattended-ugrades](https://wiki.debian.org/AutomatedUpgrade#unattended-upgrades)